# VScode isn't highlighting html close tags in PHP files

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode isn't highlighting HTML close tags after click on it in PHP files. In HTML file all is fine.
Example:

[image: HTML file, oneclick on div]

HTML file, oneclick on div (highligh open and close tag)

[image: HTML file, doubleclick on div (count all occurrences)]

HTML file, doubleclick on div (count all occurrences)

[image: And PHP file, it doesn't matter - oneclick or doubleclick - it always count all occurerences]

And PHP file, it doesn't matter - oneclick or doubleclick - it always count all occurerences

I'm not sure, it's bug or feature but I would be really happy if I could find html close tags in my php file (like in html file). Especially in more complex projects.

Comment: did you find any solution? same problem here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having the same problem and it's very frustrating.
As temporary solution I've installed the extension [Auto Rename Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-rename-tag) and when I want to know which close tag belongs to an opening tag, I change `div` to `diva` and see which close tag changes to `diva` and then change it back to `div`.

EDIT:

Alternatively, you can also set `editor.renderIndentGuides` to `true` in your user settings:

```
{    
    //some other settings
    "editor.renderIndentGuides": true
}
```

This is how it looks like now:

[image: Visual Studio Code]

Answer (score -1):

Just install this extension and hopefully, it will work -> PHP Intelephense